# redirect a page to root using htaccess

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

This is about a WP site that is using the following permalinks:
http://example.com/article/%postname%/
and category base of "categories".

Site has many articles with permalinks such as:
 
http://example.com/article/
http://example.com/article/first-article
http://example.com/article/second-article
http://example.com/article/third-article
etc.

They are working fine but I want to redirect
http://example.com/article
to
http://example.com/

So I edit htaccess and insert the following directive:
Redirect 301 /article http://example.com

While this redirect works it actually breaks the WP permalinks because an article with permalink of
http://example.com/article/third-article
is being redirected to
http://example.com/third-article which results in a 404

Can I redirect only http://example.com/article to root and no other child url?

Comment: `^article$` add ^ and $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, by either using mod_rewrite, or [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch).

With `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch ^/article/?$ http://example.com
```

With mod_rewrite:

```
RewriteRule ^article/?$ / [R,L]
```

Place this rule before the wordpress rule, and change `[R]` to `[R=301]` once everything works, and if you want to make this a permanent redirect.